# Ignore All Spaces when using DataTable.Select()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, select, datatable, whitespace

I need to select from a datatable based on a phone number.  The problem is that the phone number may have spaces in it, but these aren't necessarily consistent.

For example a phone number in the datatable could be any of the following -

01234 123 123
01234 123123
01234123123
0123 412 3123
0123 4123 123

Which is actually all the same number.

I can standardize the search string and remove spaces from that, but how can I make a search for "01234123123" match the column that actually contains "0123 412 3123" or any other variant?

`DataTable.Select("phoneNumber LIKE '" + searchString + "%'")`

Will only return the row if the number matches exactly.

I have thought of looping through and generating many variations of the searchString with spaces in all the possible places and then searching for all of them but that seems very resource intensive...

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq and remove all white-spaces, for example:

```
Dim phoneNumber = "01234 123   123"
Dim trimmedNumber = phoneNumber.Replace(" ", "")
Dim filtered = From row In DataTable
               Let trimmed = row.Field(Of String)("phoneNumber").Replace(" ", "")
               Where trimmed = trimmedNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is a way to get the information you want, as Tim has shown, but you should consider fixing the data so you don't need a workaround.  You should fix the data so it all fits the same pattern, by either removing all the spaces or making sure they have spaces in the same place.  Fixing the data on the db is easy, just use an update statement to replace all the spaces and then if you want you can use string manipulation to make all the numbers match.  The hard part is that you will need to go back into any code, if you can, and make sure the code that inserts or updates the phone number doesn't allow it to get into a bad state.  I am as guilty as anyone here for using the band-aid solution, but more often than not, you are creating a future headache for yourself.

HTH

Wade

Comment: I completely agree with your point, but unfortunately the data is coming from a spreadsheet that could be filled out by any number of people.  If I had my way I would replace it with a database but "it's always been in a spreadsheet"(!).

Comment: In that case I would use access or some other lightweight db to import the spreadsheet into and then massage the data.  If that is not possible, you could use vba or other built in features of Excel to keep the user from putting in incorrect data.  Excel 2010 has a feature to validate user input (not sure about the other versions).